# stickytableheaders firefox not working properly. <th> shows bottom of the browser

Tags: jquery, firefox

I was trying couple of days to show the  tab freeze by useing `jquery.stickhtableheaders.js` but unfortunately it does not works properly in firefox.

The table header shows bottom of the browser and the table header are overlap with other horizontal tables.

```js
$("table").stickyTableHeaders();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/master/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js"></script>

<table id="total_cost_tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table_bug_report">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="span3">Unit</th>
      <th class="span2">Unit Cost</th>
      <th class="span2">Qty</th>
      <th class="span4">Total Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Revenue_Component_total_cost_content">
    <tr>
      <td class="H29 CENTER">4</td>
      <td class="H29 CENTER">5</td>
      <td class="H29 CENTER">6</td>
      <td class="H29 CENTER">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="height: 29px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="Capital_Component_total_cost_content">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="Revenue_Component_sub_total_total_cost" name="Revenue_Component_sub_total_total_cost" class="span12 bold" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="height: 29px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="Capital_Component_sub_total_total_cost" name="Capital_Component_sub_total_total_cost" class="span12 bold" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="physical_contigency_qty" id="physical_contigency_qty" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="physical_contigency_total" id="physical_contigency_total" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="price_contigency_qty" id="price_contigency_qty" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="price_contigency_total" id="price_contigency_total" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Grand Total (a+b+c+d):</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="span12 bold" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show a more complete version of your code.

Comment: I have added the code here

Comment: still no luck, Firefox shows the table header bottom of the browser..